# How to make iPhone app look right when user is on a phone call or Internet tethering?

Tags: ios, iphone, autoresize, phone-call

The status bar has grown, so parts of my interface get cut off. Any pointers on how to fix this (e.g. using autoresize masks, etc.)?

I use Interface Builder for the UI, so everything is .xib's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally handle it with autoresize masks, or if you have custom views you can deal with it in the layoutSubviews method.

The simulator has an option "Toggle In-Call Status" you can use for testing it out without having to load it on the phone calling yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question, I think ;-)  Autoresize masks.  Ensure that all your views can resize vertically.  You can do this simply in IB on the size tab of the inspector.